# Double clone to avoid lifetime issues in rust

Tags: rust

I have this code that works:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Board {}

impl Board {
    fn free_ok_moves(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = String> {
        vec!["hello".to_string()].into_iter()
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Game {
    board: Board
}

impl Game {
    fn legal_games(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Game> {
        let s = self.clone();
        s.board.free_ok_moves().map(move |_| s.clone())
    }
}
```

But I don't understand, why I need to `clone` 2 times in `legal_games` and why doing so works. How can I avoid to `clone` twice or at all?

Here are some fail cases:

Try replacing these `fn legal_games` definitions to see the error message given below.

```
fn legal_games(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Game> {
    let s = self.clone();
    s.board.free_ok_moves().map(|_| s.clone())
}
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `s`, which is owned by the current function
```

```
fn legal_games(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Game> {
    let s = self.clone();
    s.board.free_ok_moves().map(move |_| s)
}
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `s`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
```

```
fn legal_games(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Game> {
    let s = self;
    s.board.free_ok_moves().map(move |_| s.clone())
}

fn legal_games(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Game> {
    self.board.free_ok_moves().map(move |_| self.clone())
}
fn legal_games(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Game> {
    self.board.free_ok_moves().map(|_| self.clone())
}
error[E0700]: hidden type for `impl Iterator<Item = Game>` captures lifetime that does not appear in bounds
```

```
fn legal_games(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Game> {
    self.board.free_ok_moves().map(|_| *self)
}
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*self`, as `self` is a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
```

```
fn legal_games(self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Game> {
    self.board.free_ok_moves().map(move |_| self)
}

fn legal_games(self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Game> {
    self.board.free_ok_moves().map(|_| self)
}
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and please properly format your code, see [formatting help](/help/formatting) to find out how to.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=903a9dde6a2a505a2b5ad5079e222fab

Comment: Can you also show the code that doesn't work and the compiler error on the lifetime error you're trying to avoid?

Comment: I can change and tweak a million ways to make it give me error. I can do whatever I want to this code to make it work. Just show me what feasible neat options I have. To be honest I have no idea what I am trying to do.

Comment: Then add any of the million ways to the post

Comment: If you have no idea then maybe try reading some of the basics of borrowing and lifetimes in Rust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure what you're having problem understanding with, but here are some alternatives you might want to use:

### Not cloning at all

Since you don't get something owned and `Game` isn't `Copy` either you can't return an iterator that gives owned `Game` but you can slightly tweak the signature so you return an iterator over `&Game`

```rust
fn legal_games(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &Game> {
    self.board.free_ok_moves().map(move |_| self)
}
```

It works because the lifetime while being elided is still there in the `&Game`

### Lazily cloning once for each iteration

Since all of your attempts return an iterator over owned `Game`s this might be what you're after, it's a bit of a tricky case since the iterator does depend on the lifetime of `&self` so the compiler forces you to acknowledge that, you can simply introduce a new lifetime:

```rust
fn legal_games<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Game> + 'a {
    self.board.free_ok_moves().map(move |_| self.clone())
}
```

or apply the fix suggested by the compiler:

> ```
> error[E0700]: hidden type for `impl Iterator<Item = Game>` captures lifetime that does not appear in bounds
>   --> src/lib.rs:18:9
>    |
> 16 |     fn legal_games(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Game> {
>    |                    -----     -------------------------- opaque type defined here
>    |                    |
>    |                    hidden type `Map<impl Iterator<Item = String>, [closure@src/lib.rs:18:40: 18:48]>` captures the anonymous lifetime defined here
> 17 |         
> 18 |         self.board.free_ok_moves().map(move |_| self.clone())
>    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>    |
> help: to declare that `impl Iterator<Item = Game>` captures `'_`, you can add an explicit `'_` lifetime bound
>    |
> 16 |     fn legal_games(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Game> + '_ {
>    |                                                         ++++
> ```

```rust
fn legal_games(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Game> + '_ {
    self.board.free_ok_moves().map(move |_| self.clone())
}
```

The lifetime of the iterator depends on the one of `self` because iterators are evaluated lazily, that means that all the copies aren't being made in the `legal_games` function, but only when you consume the iterator returned by it, but to make the copies the iterator has to hold on to the reference to `self`.

### Eagerly cloning for each iteration inside of `legal_games`

Instead of waiting to clone self for each iteration when the iterator is consumed, you can do all the cloning right in `legal_games` but that requires `collect`ing the iterator (and thus allocating space for each `Game`) and turning that collection into a fresh iterator.

```rust
    fn legal_games(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Game> {
        self.board.free_ok_moves().map(move |_| self.clone()).collect::<Vec<_>>().into_iter()
    }
```